# node - stream huge objects via http

Tags: node.js, http, stream

It's easy to stream `buffer` and `string` from a client to an http server. What about objects?

In general, stream supports `objectMode` for such cases, but the `Http` module doesn't seem to support it.

My use case is streaming large binary files, while each file has some custom metadata.

Currently, I use `tar-stream` and abuse the `name` property to squeeze my metadata, but I reached the limit there.

Edit, to make it clearer how I want to send the data:

```
const data = [
  { name: 'foo', description: 'long string', buffer: <huge-binary-buffer> },
  { name: 'bar', description: 'long string', buffer: <huge-binary-buffer> },
]
```

In an ideal world I could stream the `Readable.from(data)`. However, as described, it doesn't work with http.

Comment: You could put the metadata into a separate JSON file, then tar it together with your binary file and stream the tarball.  The recipient can then access either the JSON metadata or the binary data.

Comment: that's an option if I had all the data beforehand, however, I stream the data and I have the metadata of a file only once I load it from a file system. I do some manipulation on it and send it to the client with the metadata I generate for it.

Comment: Well, if you have to read through the whole file to collect the metadata anyway, I don't know what you're asking for help here with as you can't just plain stream it directly anyway.  You can read through it once, collect the metadata, then use my suggestion.  Or, if you're loading the whole giant file into memory anyway, then load it, collect the metadata and then use my suggestion.  It's completely unclear what you're asking for help with here.

Comment: The point here is that I stream lots of files. So, yes, to collect the metadata I have to read the file, but once done I want to stream it immediately, then continue with other files. So, having one JSON with metadata about all files won't work, that's what I meant before. However, yes, you're right, I can include one JSON file for each one of the files. It can work, but doesn't sound very elegant (I have to keep track and attach each file to its JSON counterpart). I hope I could somehow utilize the object-mode in http. I edited my question with a clearer example.

Comment: I don't see how object mode for a stream is relevant here because you don't want the big binary data to be a property in an object and as far as I know, object properties from object mode must be buffered internally to create the object.  You want that to be a stream.  I wonder if your server response could be a multi-part MIME format where the first MIME part was a JSON file of your data and the second MIME part for your binary data.  Or, perhaps the JSON data could be in one or more response headers.  Either way, you're going to have to collect the whole metadata before you start streaming.